# MySQL query in PHP using a variable as a name of a column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to do a MySQLi query in PHP but the name of one of the columns is stored in a variable (`$year`):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT table4.Country, AVG('.$year.')  AS 'Total' 
                             FROM table4 
                             WHERE table4.Region IN ($region)");
```

This query returns 0 as average value. I think that the problem could be that `$year` is a number and I don't know if a column can have an integer as name.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: instead of `$year` you need the column name which can not be an integer

Comment: And get prepared for the `prepared statements` enthusiast; hint: use `PDO`

Comment: *"$year is a number and I don't know if a column can have an integer as name"* - If your input is a number but the column can't be a number then what exactly is this code meant to do?  It looks like you're trying to take the average of a *string*, not a *column*, which also doesn't make much sense.  And that string will always begin and end with a dot, too.

Comment: Can you provide a table schema as well as desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not proper. As per your code MySQL will try to find the AVG('.$year.') which is not a valid expression. This needs to be changed.

So, assuming the $year contains field name which is non-integer, Try this below code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT table4.Country, AVG(`".$year."`)  AS 'Total' FROM table4 WHERE table4.Region IN ($region)");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Updated the Answer.